# InputConnectionWrapper.commitText StackOverflowError in HTC devices

Tags: android

Debug in HTC D820U, found StackOverflowError.
Device: HTC D820u, Android 6.0 ,HTC version:1.0.0.D820u
See log:

> 01-11 10:55:33.101 11234-11234/com.xxx E/CrashReport:
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:42)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:43)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:82)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper.commitText(InputConnectionWrapper.j
>   01-11 10:55:33.101 11234-11234/com.xxx E/CrashReport:
>
> ## ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

About log, No crash about my app.
Is this an Android bug? or HTC Rom bug?

Comment: Same on Nexus 5. Looks like it's android profiler bug. You can fix it by disabling advanced profiling in Run configuration.

Comment: @ookami.kb why not post this as an answer, it's 100% correct. :)

Comment: @ubuntudroid fixed :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I'm getting the same error Nexus 5. Looks like it's Android profiler bug. You can fix it by disabling advanced profiling in Run configuration:
[image]

**UPDATE:** According to [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76404689) this should be fixed in Android Studio 3.1 beta 1.

**UPDATE 2:** @ilyamuromets confirms issue to be solved in AS 3.1.1

Comment: unbelievable but true

Comment: I reported an issue for this bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76404689

Comment: nice! got this problem after android studio update today

Comment: Yes.. AS 3.0 to AS 3.1... And it affects only Android 5 & 6 only.

Comment: This should be on developers.android.com front page. I went insane with this bug!

Comment: Thank you for this! Such a strange bug. I had initially fixed it by building non-debuggable to my phones (which would turn off the profiler), but it came back again today. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, so weird... went crazy trying to find the cause!

Comment: Just started getting it after the 3.1 update. Thanks! Saved me so much time!

Comment: you cracked it boss. awesome... (y)

Comment: Helped me, also disabled Instant Run and clean + rebuild

Comment: I have the same issue on my nexus 5 android 6.0.1 after upgrade AS from 3.0.1 to 3.1 stable channel. I fix it with disable Advanced Profiling, but how to use Advanced Profiling for such devices?
Clean/rebuild doesn't help.

Comment: @ilyamuromets they say that issue should have been resolved in AS 3.1.1. Did you install this version?

Comment: Seeing this with 3.1.2 with an Android 6.0 device still