# Android Studio 3.1 EditText StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

After updating to Android Studio 3.1 I'm facing exception when EditText in focus

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: <package>, PID: 18938
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getTextBeforeCursor(InputConnectionWrapper.java:46)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

**Update:**

After some research I found out that StackOverflowError appears with different stacktraces with simple EditText:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

When trying to enter any symbol I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: <package>, PID: 21122
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.beginBatchEdit(InputConnectionWrapper.java:106)
```

When I press back:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: <package>, PID: 21280
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
```

Even entering text in WebView causing this error

In AS 3.0 EditText's worked normal

Comment: Could you please add some code

Comment: this seems like a recursive error

Comment: Can u please post the edittext onChangeListener functionality if you have added

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Did you update the Support Library version?

Comment: @MateiSuica nope, only android gradle plugin

Comment: Can u try after remove `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf`  property?

Comment: @SelimYILDIZ still not working, even with FrameLayout as root container

Comment: I have the same problem, creating a new project with an EditText works fine, but adding an EditText anywhere in my existing project causes this problem.

Comment: Opening the same project in Android Studio 3.2 Canary 8 works fine no issue. Seems like a bug in 3.1

Comment: @tagy22 that could have been a good temporary decision but as with 3.1 only release build work for me

Comment: Try to disable the advanced profiling (API < 26). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199357/inputconnectionwrapper-committext-stackoverflowerror-in-htc-devices)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As [@evi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437766/evi) pointed out there is [a bug in advanced profiling](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76404689).

For now disabling it *(Edit configuration settings -> Profiling -> Enable advanced profiling)* prevents EditText from crashing

**Update:**

Fix released in [Android Studio 3.1.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#3-1-0)

Advanced profiling available once again!

Comment: Although my comments are being deleted (hello there, mod) this is the working solution

Comment: Thanks, this bug drive me crazy since ive installed the 3.1 release of Android Studio

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I had trouble finding the option. Maybe it helps others.  I found it under Run->Edit Configurations... (profiling tab)

Comment: @AlanTodtenkopf tap on help menu and search for "Edit configuration settings" hope this helps

Comment: This issue seems not to be fully fixed in 3.1.1. Relevant ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77764953

Comment: I am on 3.1.3 and just had this problem occur after I started targeting API 26.  I'm running an API 23 emulator.  Disabling the advanced profiling made it go away.

Answer (score 7):

This seems only happens on Android 6.0 devices, the EditText works fine on Android 5 and android 7 devices. Disable advanced profiling (API < 26) in the run configuration works for me.

Comment: This worked for me too, right solution if you are using Android 6.0 devices

Comment: have you tried to upgrade Android studio to 3.1.1, that should already fix the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Android 5.1.1, same problem. Seems to a bug in new Android Studio. Disabling advanced profiling fixes the problem for debug build.

Answer (score 2):

Faced with same EditText issues just right after update to Android Studio 3.1. Try to set `debuggable false` in `build.gradle` for debug build type. Or just switch to release build type since it's false by default. That helped in my case.

**Update:** Confirming that disabling advanced profiling fixed my issue as well.

Comment: Release build does seem to work. Although I don't know why or how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after:

- Deleting .idea, .gradle, gradle folder and recreate it.
- Clean project.
- Rebuild app.

it works for me.