# Android EditText causes OutOfMemoryError when tapped

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory

I created an app which i recently refactored to use ViewModel and Fragments.
At some time i run in to a problem: every time i tapped on a Edittext (or a subclass of it like EditTextInputLayout) my app crashes with an out of memory exeption. I don't even need to start typing to cause this error. The error occures everywhere, no matter if the EditText is part of a fragment, a simple activity or a Dialog.

`05-23 12:44:55.712 13497-13497/com.ignates.myconomy E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 75738220 byte allocation with 16769200 free bytes and 54MB until OOM
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
        at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
        at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:343)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:67)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:51)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:93)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)`

**What i did:**

- I used the Android Profiler trying to get a clue of what is going on. But since im not experienced in profiling i just coud determine that it allocates
  a lot of String, char[] and StringBuilder instances.
- I commented out any extension function on TextView or EditText
- Made sure ViewModels are implemented correctly and no instances of fragments are kept in memory

**What i know**

- At some point my every Edittext worked well, but i cant determine the actual point in time
- I am not using any BitMaps or ImageViews in my app
- The memory level rises from around 64mb to 256mb in about 5sec and then the app crashes. Also a lot of UncaughtExeptions appear in the callstack. I checked everything and don't know what causes these. Images of profiler: [Profiler callstack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjyq2.png), [Profiler memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD23y.png).

**Example fragment**

```
class SearchFragment : BaseFragment<SearchViewModel>(), SearchFragmentInterface, OnUserSelectedCallback {

val searchAdapter: SearchUserAdapter = SearchUserAdapter(this)

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)

override fun createViewModel(): SearchViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity,
        ViewModelFactory { return@ViewModelFactory SearchViewModel(activity.application, activityViewModel, this) }).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    listener.setActionBar(search_toolbar) //Sets toolbar  in activity
    search_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    search_recycler.adapter = searchAdapter
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    search_input.isCursorVisible = false

    /*search_input.onTextChange {
        if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) mViewModel.queryUsers(it)
    }*/

    mViewModel.queryResults.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { searchAdapter.setResults(it) }
    })
}

override fun onUserSelected(user: UserNamePair) = mViewModel.onUserSelected(user)

override fun onError(e: Exception?, message: String) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() = SearchFragment()
}
```

I don't have much experience in these issues. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check it -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio/35427145

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Unfortunately i don't use ImageViews and changing the manifest also doesn't solve my issuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, this error is a known bug in advanced profiling. [Disabling the option solves the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49528299/5131883). Because my editText was encapsulated in a fragment there was a diffrent error thrown and i couldn't find the other answer.