# App crashing on clicking on EditText with latest updates (gradle 4.4 - android studio 3.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-gradle-plugin, android-anr-dialog

I recently updated my android studio to version 3.1 and also my gradle to version 4.4. Since, then I have been facing this issue of app going into ANR when clicking on an `EditText` that should popup a soft input keyboard. On clicking on an `EditText` I see that there are multiple GCs that get triggered and eventually the app crashes with and ANR message saying that there is a stack overflow exceeding the size of 8 MB. Here is the crash that I see: http://crashes.to/s/77a48e5d43c. Also pasting it here:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.reportFullscreenMode(InputConnectionWrapper.java:122)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:416)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Here is a snippet of how I have used `EditText`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/login_screen_elem_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fbLogin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fbLogin">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/first_name"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionNext"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/secondaryTextColour"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**FYI**: I also face similar issue when I try to click on a text item in the my `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

Comment: Show your code on which `EditText` code written.

Comment: @EktaBhawsar updated the question with the usage of `TextInputEditText `

Comment: Can you try to hide `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionNext"` and run.

Comment: use `EditText` instead of `TextInputEditText` and remove  `flagNoExtractUi` from `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionNext"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49528299/5148289

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** There is one other reason to this error, `Android Profiler`s
>   bug. Disabling `Advanced Profiling` on **Profiling** Tab, in **Run/Debug configurations** may fix it.

Here related other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112444/3669559

[image]

---

You are getting **java.lang.StackOverflowError** which means most possibly you have calling some methods recursively and continuously. That causes infinite loop and this error.

If you have **TextWatcher** or any listener like **OnFocusChangeListener** on this `EditText`, you need to check it.

Comment: I just checked. I don't have any listeners attached on my `TextInputEditText `

Comment: This was the reason indeed. Thank you :)

Comment: Fixed in AS 3.1.1 https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html

Answer (score 3):

In the new release of Android Studio 3.1, there is a bug in advanced profiling.

So, You just disabling it (In menu bar Run -> Edit configurations -> Profiling -> Enable advanced profiling) prevents `EditText` from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Android Studio fixes this problem, 3.1.1. Had the problem and tested the fix myself moments ago. Hope that helps!