# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB on android studio. How to solve it?

Tags: java, android

As my application i run in android studio got this problem.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.brain_storming, PID: 11742
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at com.example.user.brain_storming.MusicService$1.onError(MusicService.java:48)
        at com.example.user.brain_storming.MusicService$1.onError(MusicService.java:48)
```

And i have check the code the line 48 is this

```
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
                extra) {

            onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I dun know how to solve it and i had go to enable the advanced profiling as i refer to this website. But its not work =(

[InputConnectionWrapper.commitText StackOverflowError in HTC devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199357/inputconnectionwrapper-committext-stackoverflowerror-in-htc-devices)

The code below is my music service code

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private int length = 0;

    public MusicService() {
    }

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.play);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.setVolume(50, 50);
        }


        /*mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
                    extra) {

                onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
                return true;
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.start();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void pauseMusic() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.pause();
                length = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            }
        }
    }

    public void resumeMusic() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.seekTo(length);
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void startMusic() {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.play);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.setVolume(50, 50);
            mPlayer.start();
        }

    }

    public void stopMusic() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this method is calling itself infinitely.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Comment: Inside `onError` method, you call itself again. That why you get `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: @Eran Dun know. As i learning how to add background music and online teach me this way

Comment: @Zoe Sorry. I will mention it next time

Comment: @Tommy So should i comment out that line? ```onError(mPlayer, what, extra);```

Comment: It based on your achievement, if you want to handle when an error occurs, then put your code there. Otherwise just remove `mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
                extra) {

            onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
            return true;
        }
    });`.

Comment: @Tommy But it will affect anything? If i comment out that code?

Comment: Can you show your `MusicService` class?

Comment: @Tommy I add that class in the post edited

Comment: @JohnLee Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** You are calling wrong `onError` method. You must calling `onError` of `MusicService` instead.

**Solution:** Change your code from

```
mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
            extra) {
        onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
        return true;
    }
});
```

to

```
mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
            extra) {
        // Calling onError of MusicService instead this onError method.
        MusicService.this.onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
        return true;
    }
});
```